# List Files in a Directory Sorted by Creation Time

Tags: go

I know how to list the files in a directory using `ioutil.ReadDir()`... but how do I sort them by creation time (from oldest to newest)? I'm using `go 8.3`.

Comment: What file system do you use?

Comment: Ext4 on Fedora Linux

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On Linux you cannot, and Go has nothing to do with it (creation time is simply not stored in most Linux file systems). On Windows you can, but not with the go standard library. Well, it may be possible with the value returned by `(os.FileInfo).Sys()`, but you would be better served to look for a library.

Sorting by the *last modified* time is fairly easy:

```
files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(path)
// TODO: handle the error!
sort.Slice(files, func(i,j int) bool{
    return files[i].ModTime().Before(files[j].ModTime())
})
```

Comment: The OP uses EXT4 so you're wrong https://dzone.com/articles/ext4-crtime-creation-time

Comment: True, but note two things: The comment specifying the OP's file system is newer than this answer, and the *Go standard library* does not support this, so you would still need to hack something together.

Comment: This code no longer compiles (go 1.11) with the error "operator < not defined on time.Time".  Note that the solution by Alexandr (with .Unix()) will compile

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I have updated it. Remember, you can always edit answers yourself!

Answer (score 4):

```
files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(path)
//TODO
sort.Slice(files, func(i,j int) bool{
    return files[i].ModTime().Unix() < files[j].ModTime().Unix()
})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Same as Milo Christiansen just sorts it by unix time